# How can draw frame by frame animation on image view, both visible simultaneously in Android?

Tags: android

I want to draw animation on image view and the image position is changing on run time if user successfully tap on the image then an animation is to be draw.Here is my code

```
    public void enter() {  //To enter in to animation
        setBackgroundResource(R.anim.dhakkan_animation);
        frameByframe_animation = (AnimationDrawable) getBackground();
        frameByframe_animation.start();
        frameByframe_animation.setOneShot(true); 
    }

    @Override
    public void exit() {
                                //when exit from Animation
        frameByframe_animation.stop();
        frameByframe_animation.setVisible(false, false); 
    }
```

the problem is that when animation darws my image of image view get invisible. According to my requirement i have to show both simultaneously in background an image(image of image view) and in foreground animation play.Plese help me im totally frustated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show imageView, when your animation goes, just do it in *.xml:

```
            <ImageView    android:id=@+id/s210    .....    android:src="@drawable/s210 />
```

Comment: Heartly thanks timonvlad for replay my image view's image is contineously  changes at run time. Its not static.And each frame draw they may or may not be different images.